# Error framework-extra-bundle Anotation "Unable to parse file [...] The XML file is not valid."

Tags: php, xml, symfony, iis

There is a recurring error in my Symfony projects since a few months. Every time a file at the root of the project is edited (even a space add in an a.txt file will reproduce the bug), I get this error.

> Unable to parse file "[RootPath]\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\src\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\annotations.xml":
> The XML file "[RootPath]\vendor\sensio\framework-extra-bundle\src\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\annotations.xml" is not valid.

[image: XML error]

The error is remove with the command line `symfony console cache:clear`.

<s>I think this error is linked to PhpStorm because I get it when I edit a root file with it, but the error is not reproducible when I edit a root file with VSCode or Notepad++.</s>

I am using PhpStorm version 2021.2 and also tried with 2021.1.4 and 2020.3.3. I tried to disable all PhpStorm plugins.

The project is made with Symfony 5.3 but the error is reproduced with an older project using Symfony 5.1

Does someone knows how to resolve this or have an idea of what I could try to solve it?

**Edit:**
Here is the content of annotations.xml :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="sensio_framework_extra.controller.listener" class="Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener">
            <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
            <argument type="service" id="annotation_reader" />
        </service>
    </services>
</container>
```

I found no modification in the annotations.xml file before, during and after the error.

**Edit2:**

With more test, this bug is reproduced every time a file is deleted or created at the root even with another tool like VS Code or Windows explorer.

The error is produced on modification only with PhpStorm, so I guess it create and delete a temp file or something similar when editing a file.

Comment: Have you checked what the mentioned fie actually contains? And put that through a tool that checks XML for wellformed-ness at least yet?

Comment: 1) The error is reported by the Symfony and not PhpStorm. 2) The path of the file where error occurs seems to be the `vendor` folder, so it's part of the framework. The IDE does not allow to edit such files with default settings (gives a warning/treats them as read-only). If the file is actually gets changed / edited .. then most likely this would be one of the plugins. I suggest disable ALL custom (not bundled by default) plugins, restart the IDE and try again -- any difference? If it works OK after that then enable plugins 1-2 at a time until you find a guilty one.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I found no modification in the annotations.xml file before, during and after the error. 

I try to validate it with https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp, this return no error.

I will edit the question to include the XML. 

I already try to disable all plugins (Including the one activate by default ) and the error was still here

Comment: The links `xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"` seems to be dead.  But like the links are the same when there is no error, I do not think if this could be the source of the error

Comment: I tried again but only with custom plugins disabled, restart the ide but the error is still the same.

Comment: No other ideas on my end. Do the following: use `Help | Contact Support...` in PhpStorm to create support ticket where you can privately provide all needed info to JetBrains Support Team. 1) Use "Help | Show log in XXX" to locate `idea.log` file; 2) Close IDE 3) delete any log files there (back them up first). 3) Launch IDE and reproduce the issue. 4) use `Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data` and include all those logs when contacting PhpStorm Support.

Comment: I will keep it in a note and contact them if we do not find an awnser during this week-end. Thanks for your comments and for the spelling correction in the question LazyOne.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to come from IIS, Symfony and PHP version 8.0.8 and 8.0.10 (Others versions could cause the same issue).

Changing the IIS server's PHP version to 8.0.0 prevents the error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (symfony6, php8.1), it helped to change in the config

```
sensio_framework_extra:
    router:      { annotations: false }
```

because sensio_framework_extra package have deprecations in default config.